# Cordova won't start on device

Tags: android, cordova

I cannot deploy mycordova app on my device.
I see that on a similar question the problem was that the phone driver wasn't installed.

But in my case the driver is ok and the device is connected:

```
C:\androidsdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
4100dd1690e93100        unauthorized
```

but when I try to run myapp on the phone I get the following error:

```
c:\wscordova\myapp>cordova run android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "c:\wscordova\myapp\platforms\android\cordova\run.b
at""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\androidsdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to emulator

c:\wscordova\myapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
ERROR : No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: c:\androidsdk\tools\android.BAT sdk

2. Create an AVD by running: c:\androidsdk\tools\android.BAT avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM devi
ce driver

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit
 code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

What could it be?